# How to get real A4 paper X and Y dimensions

Tags: printing, photoshop

i have A4 paper i want to print in specific point of page using vb.net the code is fine and printing is done. i try to create A4 page in photoshop and get point X and Y dimensions from info put it gives me wrong place in print . so how to get real A4 paper X and Y dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

hi my suggestion is A4 measures 210 × 297 millimeters or 8.27 × 11.69 inches. In PostScript, its dimensions are rounded off to 595 × 842 points. Folded twice, an A4 sheet fits in a C6 size envelope (114 × 162 mm).

if any doubts - refer :
https://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size/din-a4

Answer (score 0):

PHOTOSHOP
    File-->new-->print-->A4
[click to view image prof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pHKr.jpg)

(OR)

Width:2480 pixels-- 
Height:3508 pixels